# 6th-order filter simulation

Tags: analog, adc, active-filter

I've designed a 6th-order filter using Analog Devices' online filter wizard. The filter has a cutoff frequency of 2MHz, and I'm aiming for 50dB attenuation at 5MHz, with a continued roll-off beyond that point. To achieve this, I've replaced the last stage with a multiple feedback configuration to extend the roll-off.

I have a couple of questions:

Is it a good idea to use a multiple feedback configuration in the last stage for a continued roll-off, or are there better alternatives?

When I perform noise analysis, the online tool indicates minimal noise in the noise spectral density graph beyond the filter's cutoff frequency. However, in LTSpice, I observed another peak of noise at 20MHz. I anticipated that the noise would be suppressed due to bandwidth limitations. Is my understanding correct, and if so, why does the LTSpice simulation yield different results from the online tool's noise graph?
[image: Design]
[image: Noise Density Graph in Analog Filter Wizard]
[image: Bode Plot in LTSpice]
[image: Noise in LTSpice]

Comment: The bandwidth limitations affect the signal coming into a stage. But the opamp and resistors within this stage still produce noise.

Comment: I'd swap positions of stage A and B.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why noise spectral density in wizard and LTSpice are different?

Comment: @HKet Just curious. Did you also plot LTspice's V(inoise)?

Answer (score 4):

To K Ket: Yes, I think you have selected a good design strategy.

1.)
The unity-gain S&K stages have (a) good high-frequency properties (from the opamp point of view) and (b) a good active sensitivity (against opamp non-idealities).
However, the known disadvantage is the fact that high-frequency damping is limited due to the feedback capacitor which couples a portion of the input signal directly to the opamps finite output impedance.

2.) The last stage (multiple feedback topology) can correct this systematic "error". However, other than the S&K stages, this topology has a comparable bad active sensitivity (against opamp phase distortions connected with open-loop gain characteristics).
Therefore, the used opamps should have a unity-gain frequency that is sufficiently large. More than that - don`t forget the slew rate, which should be able to handle frequenncies in the lower MHz range.

**Added**: As far as your question is concerned *(Is it a good idea to use a multiple feedback configuration in the last stage for a continued roll-off, or are there better alternatives?)* I can answer as follows:

There is a two-opamp-stage based on the GIC-principle (Generalized Impedance Converter) which is known as the "best" filter stage regarding high frequency properties. This is because the two opamps are combined in a manner which causes cancellation of opamps non-idealities up to a certain degree.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Any idea why noise spectral density in wizard and LTSpice are different?